# BibLaTeX Punctuation after parentheses

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

If an article title ends with `.)` the comma that is supposed to follow isn't there. If there is only a closing parenthesis there is also the comma. See the screenshot below.

How can this be fixed? `\DeclarePunctuationPairs{<identifier>}{<characters>}` doen't work since parentheses are not allowed for the `character` part.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  bibstyle=ext-authoryear,
  articlein=false,
]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{TEST-Bib-Sorting.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\newbibmacro*{pages}{
  \printfield{pages}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:articlein}{\usebibmacro{in:}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{filecontents}{TEST-Bib-Sorting.bib}
@Article{Meunier:2012,
  author   = {Meunier, L. J.},
  year     = {2012},
  title    = {\foreignlanguage{english}{Ennius, les astres et les théories anciennes de la vision. À propos de \emph{Sol albus} et \emph{radiis icta lux} (v. 84–85 Sk.)}},
  journal  = {RPh},
  volume   = {86},
  pages    = {101–21},
}

@Article{Soubiran:1992,
  author   = {Soubiran, J.},
  year     = {1992},
  title    = {Mythologie et astronomie: la longue nuit de Jupiter et d’Alcmène (Plaute, Amph., 272–276)},
  journal  = {Pallas},
  volume   = {38},
  pages    = {345–58},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex`'s punctuation tracker suppresses double punctuation such as `.,`. In this case you don't really have double punctuation since there is a closing parenthesis in between the two clashing punctuation commands `.),`. The tracker, however, ignores the parentheses.

For your particular issue there is a simple workaround: `biblatex` distinguishes abbreviation *dots* and sentence-ending *periods* (full stops). Usually `.` in the input is interpreted as a sentence-ending period, which can not clash with a comma. But an abbreviation dot can be combined with a comma. Hence, it is enough to tell `biblatex` that in this case the `.` signifies an abbreviation. This can be done by adding `\isdot` after the `.`.

```
@article{Meunier:2012,
  author   = {Meunier, L. J.},
  year     = {2012},
  title    = {\foreignlanguage{french}{Ennius, les astres et les théories anciennes de la vision.
              À propos de \emph{Sol albus} et \emph{radiis icta lux} (v. 84–85 Sk.\isdot)}},
  journal  = {RPh},
  volume   = {86},
  pages    = {101–21},
}
```

produces

[image: Meunier, L. J. (2012), Ennius, les astres et les théories anciennes de la vision. À propos de Sol albus et radiis icta lux (v. 84–85 Sk.), RPh 86, pp. 101–21.]

---

It would be possible to add the `\isdot` automatically in the field format with

```
 \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\isdot}
```

Indeed, the standard setting for `@article` et al. is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

which does that already. But this means that every `.` at the end of the `title` field is interpreted as an abbreviation dot and not as a sentence-ending period.

---

As mentioned above `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker ignores parentheses characters. You can un-ignore them by adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@setsfcodes{%
  \let\blx@setsfcodes\relax
  \let\frenchspacing\blx@setfrcodes
  \let\nonfrenchspacing\blx@setencodes
  \ifnum\sfcode`\.>2000
    \blx@setencodes
  \else
    \blx@setfrcodes
  \fi
  \@setquotesfcodes
  \sfcode`\(=\@m
  \sfcode`\)=\@m
  \sfcode`\[=\@m
  \sfcode`\]=\@m
  \sfcode`\<=\@m
  \sfcode`\>=\@m}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble. That means that the punctuation tracker does not jump over `)` and friends any more and instead goes back to seeing no punctuation before and after those characters.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'm impressed that there is usually such a clear and easy solution.
Do you happen to know how to fix this globally? I have way more than 2500 entries in my `.bib` file. Finding all of these cases would be a pain.

Comment: I will just add your last code snippet to my preamble. That'll do it.